Expressing internal energy of a system in thermodynamics
Recently I came across a article where it was written  that
1.$\Delta U= nC_v\Delta T$ for all thermodynamic process
2.but $\Delta U =nC_p\Delta T$ is true only in a isobaric process
How true are the above statements? What is the reason behind 1?
why can't I use $\Delta U = nCp\Delta T$ always.

The above is obviously not true since 1. Implies that internal energy depends on only temperature. In general it (at least) also depends on volume and the amount of substance.

What do you mean by "how true"? It can only be true or false.

Can you link to the article or give more details? You're getting a pile of misinformation, and it would be useful to identify the source.

Neither equation is generally accurate.
A frustrating aspect of thermodynamics is that the phrases (1) "constant volume" and "constant pressure" appear both as process conditions and in the name of certain material constants; (2) some systems—notably, the ideal gas—have simple equations of state with material properties (namely, the heat capacity) that happen to include "constant-pressure" or "constant-volume" in their name, regardless of the process or conditions; and (3) new practitioners encounter all of this early, sometimes without clarification, escalating the confusion.
It's true that the heat transfer $Q$ is $nC_X\Delta T$ when heating a simple system (and doing nothing else) under condition $X$. But it's not true that one can take an equation such as $\Delta U=nC_V\Delta T$ for the ideal gas and apply the same reasoning to switch $C_V$ for, say, $C_P$ when the pressure is held constant.
This answer is intended to step back and look at how these equations arise.
If one can either heat a system or do expansion–compression work on it, then the internal energy can be expanded in terms of two variables, such as temperature and volume,
$$dU=\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_VdT+\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_TdV\tag{1a};$$
or temperature and pressure,
$$dU=\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_PdT+\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial P}\right)_TdP\tag{2a}.$$
In addition, we have the fundamental relation
$$dU=T\,dS-P\,dV.\tag{3}$$
Carrying through the differentiation,
$$dU=T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_VdT+T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_TdV-P\,dV\tag{1b};$$
$$dU=T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_PdT-P\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_PdT+T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial P}\right)_TdP-P\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial P}\right)_TdP\tag{2b}.$$
To address some of the terms in Eqs. (1b) and (2b), by definition of the (constant-volume and constant-pressure) molar heat capacities,
$$C_V\equiv \frac{T}{n}\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_V\tag{4};$$
$$C_P\equiv \frac{T}{n}\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_P\tag{5}.$$
And by a Maxwell relation and the triple product rule,
$$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_T=\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V=-\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}\right)_T=\alpha K;$$
$$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial P}\right)_T=-\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P=-\alpha V,$$
where $\alpha\equiv\frac{1}{V}\left(\frac{\partial V}{T}\right)_P$ is the (constant-pressure) thermal expansion coefficient and $K\equiv -V\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}\right)_T$ is the (constant-temperature) bulk modulus.
Thus, we have
$$dU=nC_V\,dT+(\alpha TK-P)\,dV\tag{1c};$$
$$dU=(nC_P-\alpha PV)\,dT-V\left(\alpha T-\frac{P}{K}\right)dP\tag{2c}.$$
These are very general equations that apply regardless of the material in this context. Note especially that the equations apply even though the material properties in them happen to have "constant-volume," "constant-temperature," and "constant-pressure" in their names.
Now, in the special case of the ideal gas, $\alpha=\frac{1}{T}$, $K=P$, and $PV=nRT$; thus,
$$dU=C_V\,dT\tag{1d};$$
$$dU=(C_P-nR)\,dT=C_V\,dT\tag{2d}.$$
Note that the equations have converged and that the coefficients of $dV$ and $dP$ disappear! So it doesn't matter whether a constant-volume process or a constant-pressure process—or any process at all—is being applied to an ideal gas; its equation of state is $U=nC_V T+U_0$ (where $U_0$ is an arbitrary reference energy), and the differential form is $dU=nC_V\,dT$ (or in finite terms, $\Delta U=nC_V\Delta T$). This is always true for the ideal gas; it doesn't matter if any process is occurring. (Relatedly, the enthalpy $H=nC_PT+H_0$ for the ideal gas.)
Unfortunately for the new practitioner, the only material constant that doesn't drop out of the equations for the ideal gas—$C_V$—has "constant-volume" in its name. The understandably frustrating aspect for students is they learn to associate "constant volume" and "constant-pressure" with processes involving the heat capacity, and then run into a wall when they encounter the equation of state of the ideal gas. And I can't blame them.
In the end, the above manipulations are arguably pushing the edge of what undergrads can comfortably handle, so they often see only the results, which understandably leads to confusion because "constant volume" and "constant pressure" appear both as conditions ($dV=0$ and $dP=0$, respectively) and in the name of the material properties $C_V$ and $C_P$ (and $K$).
Is this useful? Please let me know what's unclear.

For an ideal gas (1) is true for any process, including the isobaric pressure process (2). You can find proofs on this site.
(2) should be
$$\Delta U=Q-W=nC_{p}\Delta T-P\Delta V\tag{1}$$
For an ideal gas (ideal gas law)
constant pressure process
$$\Delta V=\frac{nR\Delta T}{P}\tag{2}$$ and
$$R=C_{p}-C_{v}\tag{3}$$
Substituting eq(2) and eq(3) into eq (1) gives us
$$\Delta U=nC_{v}\Delta T\tag{4}$$
Hope this help

In general, you have that (first law of thermodynamics) $\delta Q = dU + \delta W$, which for gasses is $\delta Q = dU + P\,dV$. Now, we can use the fact that the heat capacity at constant volume or pressure is
$$
C_V := \left.\frac{\delta Q}{d T}\right|_{V=cte},\quad C_P := \left.\frac{\delta Q}{d T}\right|_{P=cte},
$$
so, we can express $U$ as a function of $T,P$, and, by using the chain rule we get
$$
\delta Q = dU + P\,dV = \left.{\frac {\partial U}{\partial T}}\right|_{P} dT + \left.{\frac {\partial U}{\partial P}}\right|_{T} dP + P \left[\left.{\frac {\partial V}{\partial T}}\right|_{P} dT + \left.{\frac {\partial V}{\partial P}}\right|_{T} dP\right],
$$
so, take for isobaric processes ($dP=0$),
$$
C_P = \left.{\frac {\partial U}{\partial T}}\right|_{P} + P \left.{\frac {\partial V}{\partial T}}\right|_{P},
$$
which can be integrated -- assuming $C_P$ independent of $T$, which can usually be a good approximation if we are dealing with small temperature ranges -- to find that $\Delta T C_P = \Delta U + P\Delta V$.
Meanwhile, if we express $U$ in terms of $T,V$,
$$
\delta Q = \left.{\frac {\partial U}{\partial T}}\right|_{V} dT + \left.{\frac {\partial U}{\partial V}}\right|_{T} dV + P dV,
$$
at constant volume ($dV=0$), we may simplify this to $\delta Q = dU$, so
$$
\delta Q = \left.{\frac {\partial U}{\partial T}}\right|_{V} dT \implies C_V = \left.{\frac {\partial U}{\partial T}}\right|_{V}, 
$$
which becomes $\Delta U = C_V \Delta T$, once integrated, as claimed! Here I have assumed that $C_V$ is independent of $T$, which can usually be a good approximation if we are dealing with small temperature ranges.

The simplification in your isobaric section is misleading. If $dP=0$ and $\Delta V=0$, as you assume, then $\Delta T=0$ and the coefficient you have as $C_P$ could be anything. The correct relation at constant pressure is $\Delta U=(C_P-PV\alpha)\Delta T$, where $\alpha\equiv\frac{1}{V}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P$ is the thermal expansion coefficient. (For an ideal gas, $\alpha=\frac{1}{T}$, and thus $\Delta U=(C_P-\frac{PV}{T})\Delta T=(C_P-nR)\Delta T=C_V\Delta T$.)

@Chemomechanics Thank you, I have deleted that part of my answer.
